# Call another observer method in current model observer

Tags: laravel, model, observers

In laravel I want to call another observers deleting method in my current model observer. Is that possible?
for example lets say I have observers for product and category, So I want to call productobservers deleting method in categoryobservers deleting loop.

```
public function deleting(Category $Category)
    {
        DB::transaction(function () use($Category) { 
            $Category->products->each(function ($products) { 
                //call product observer deleting function
            });
    
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set your event in this array like this

```php
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'saved' => UserSaved::class,
        'deleted' => UserDeleted::class,
    ];
}
```

and create listener for those events